# Flatpickr.js show first letter of the day only

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flatpickr

I cannot find in the documentation how to make the first letter of the day show up only.
By default it's showing Mon Tue etc ...
I would like to be showing it like below example

https://jsfiddle.net/wdL13cty/8/

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {

  var datesToEnable = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('dates').innerHTML);
  console.log(datesToEnable);
  var fp = flatpickr(document.querySelector('#flatpickr'), {
    // init flatpicker as an inline NON modal date picker
    // min date today
    // disable all dates
    // enable dates coming from JSON object
    // able to change the datge format if necessary
    inline: 'true',
    altFormat: "F j, Y",
    altInput: true,
    minDate: "today",
    disableMobile: "true",
    enable: datesToEnable.dates,
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      console.log('date: ', dateStr);
    }
  });

});
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share your code? Preferably a short working example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `locale` config option to customize the label as per your requirement.
See the official documentation here: [Localization](https://flatpickr.js.org/localization/)

Example:

```
flatpickr(myElem, {
    locale: {
        firstDayOfWeek: 2
    }
});
```

Working sample:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {

  var datesToEnable = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('dates').innerHTML);
  console.log(datesToEnable);
  var fp = flatpickr(document.querySelector('#flatpickr'), {
    // init flatpicker as an inline NON modal date picker
    // min date today
    // disable all dates
    // enable dates coming from JSON object
    // able to change the datge format if necessary
    inline: 'true',
    altFormat: "F j, Y",
    altInput: true,
    minDate: "today",
    disableMobile: "true",
    enable: datesToEnable.dates,
    locale: {
      weekdays: {
        shorthand: ["S", "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S"]
      }
    },
    onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      console.log('date: ', dateStr);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display: none;
}
.flatpickr-monthDropdown-months {
  -webkit-appearance: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.3/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flatpickr/4.6.3/flatpickr.min.js"></script>
<script type="application/json" id="dates">
  {
        "dates": ["2020-06-20", "2020-06-21", "2020-06-24"]
    }
</script>
<input type='text' id="flatpickr" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I also had to add in the `longhand` days in too (even if they weren't changing) otherwise it threw an error.

`longhand: [ "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"] }`

Answer (score 0):

if you have define the Flatficker js and css, you can simply costumize the property of that.
here the documentation  [https://unpkg.com/flatpickr@2.0.5/index_.html][Property]

```js
let Flatpickr = document.getElementById("date").flatpickr({
 dateFormat: "Y-m-d H:i"
});

Flatpickr.l10n.weekdays.shorthand = ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S']
document.getElementById('date').flatpickr();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>


<input id="date" type='text' placeholder="Select Date..">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    $('.flatpickr-weekday')[i].textContent = $('.flatpickr-weekday')[i].textContent.replace(/\s/g, '').slice(0, 2);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.